# ¿Cómo editar el usuario y el host en mostrado en la terminal?

Tags: terminal, unix, fedora

Actualmente estoy usando por primera vez Fedora, y tengo el problema de que los datos propios de la terminal son muy largos

[image: como se puede ver la imagen]

¿Cual sería la manera correcta de acortar toda la información mostrada? Pensaba en una solución como la usada por la terminal de Parrot OS, o alguna otra solución elegante?

Comment: Checa https://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-user-hostname-terminal-prompt/

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez muchas gracias, es justo lo que buscaba, si lo escribes como respuesta, lo podría marcar tu respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Pasos para cambiar el usuario y el host en bash

1. Abre el archivo de configuración `.bashrc` ubicado en el `home` con el editor de tu preferencia. Puedes hacerlo desde la terminal usando:

```
code ~/.bashrc  # Para editarlo con Vscode
nano ~/.bashrc  # Para abrirlo con nano
```

2. Encuentra la línea que comienza con `PS1=`. La línea debe lucir de similar a `PS1='[\u@\h \W]$ '` donde `\u` representa el nombre de usuario,`\h` representa el host y `\W` tu ubicación actual en el ordenador. Justo esta línea es la que define el formato de usuario en la consola, y es la que debes editar. Cámbiala a:

- `PS1='[\W]\$ '` para mostrar solo el nombre del directorio en el que estás. Algo como:

```
[Desktop]$
```

- `PS1='\$ '` para mostrar solo el símbolo de dolar `$`:

```
$
```

O bien personalízala como gustes.

3. Finalmente guarda los cambios en el archivo y ejecuta en terminal el comando `source ~/.bashrc` para cargar los cambios que guardaste. Con esto ya deberías ver el cambio en la consola.

Puedes checar más detalles en https://www.maketecheasier.com/remove-user-hostname-terminal-prompt/.

Comment: En mi caso la linea `PS1='[\u@\h \W]$ '` no exitía previamente en el archivo, en esta situación es suficiente con agregar la linea al archivo.